# ExtJS menu checkItem: how to prevent item check event in certain circumstance?

Tags: events, extjs, click

for a menu checkItem, when user clicks at it, by default it will trigger checkchange; i am wondering how to, if a certain case is met, not change its check status after clicked, in other words, stop this event chain.

I tried following codes, but not work:

```
listeners: {
'click': function(item, evt) {
    if(1) { //verify whether that certain case
        evt.stopEvent(); //since click_event is triggered before setChecked()/checkChange, I thought this may stop its going further...
        alert('case met!');
    }
},
checkHandler: function(item, checked) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to the `beforecheckchange` event. [Here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.menu.CheckItem-event-beforecheckchange) it is in the docs.

As per the docs, just apply your conditional logic and if it doesn't pass, return false from the handler.

E.g.:

```
listeners: {
    'beforecheckchange': function(item, checked) {
        if(!1) { // or whatever your conditional logic is
            return false;
        }
    },
}
```