# Extjs how to capture when the checkbox is checked or unchecked in xtype: 'checkcolumn'

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I am new to EXTJS. I have a grid , where I have checkbox column . What I wanted is , how to capture the  check or uncheck events  happening in the  checkbox .

Here is my code for checkbox in my grid

```
    columns : [

             {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                   header: 'Enabled',
              dataIndex: 'isEnabled',
              width: 55
           },
        ....
         ]
```

Please help

Comment: It's in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Check-event-checkchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just what Evan Trimboli said, with the `checkchange` event on the grid you can capture when a checkbox changes value.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    //...
    columns  : [{ 
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        header: 'Enabled',
        dataIndex: 'isEnabled',
        width: 55,
        listeners: {
            checkchange: function(column, rowIdx, checked, eOpts){
                //Logic here
            }
        }
    }],
});
```

Comment: checkchange event is not provided on grid, rather it is available on column.

Comment: Is there a way to block the check box from editing from this event? For example, if we do some logic and then uncheck...

Comment: @KremenaLalova Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089323/extjs-menu-checkitem-how-to-prevent-item-check-event-in-certain-circumstance)

Answer (score 1):

There is a little change in the give answer, the checkchange event is for Ext.grid.column.check not for Ext.grid.Panel

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
//...
columns  : [{ 
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    header: 'Enabled',
    dataIndex: 'isEnabled',
    width: 55,
    listeners: {
        checkchange: function(column, rowIdx, checked, eOpts){
            //Logic here
    }
    }
}]
});
```